# How to call Oracle function which has SYS_REFCURSOR as OUT Parameter

Tags: sql, oracle, call, sql-function

```
create or replace
FUNCTION test_fun (
p_ref_cur               OUT SYS_REFCURSOR,
p_a_code            IN  NUMBER                                  DEFAULT 0,
p_category          IN  package.category%TYPE           DEFAULT NULL,
p_name              IN  package.name%TYPE           DEFAULT NULL,
p_display_name      IN  package.display_name%TYPE   DEFAULT NULL,
p_rowid             IN  package."rowid"%TYPE                DEFAULT NULL,
p_flg               IN  package.flg%TYPE                DEFAULT '1',
p_mod_dat           IN  package.mod_dat%TYPE            DEFAULT SYSTIMESTAMP,
p_mod_usr           IN  package.mod_usr%TYPE            DEFAULT NULL
)
RETURN NUMBER
AS
```

How to call this function in oracle which has SYS_REFCURSOR as OUT parameter?

**Update:**
**test_fun** will be called from another function say **caller()** where the complete function to be executed will be taken from the database and execute using execute immediate command.

```
SELECT command into cmd from data_table where id=p_id;
execute immediate (cmd);
```

**cmd** value will be like

`test_fun(v_cv1,0, 'pp', 'np123', 'np', NULL, 1, NULL, 'testuser');`

**NOTE:** We have control over the **caller()** function and **cmd** to be execute but no control over **test_fun()**

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Is there any specific reason why you don't declare the cursor as IN OUT?

Comment: Thats how it is. I don't have any control over it.

Comment: Which SQL client are you using? Handling of ref cursors is *very* client specific.

Answer (score 0):

Just declare a variable of type SYS_REFCURSOR in the calling block, and call your function, e.g. from SQL/Plus:

```
 set autoprint on;
 var cur refcursor;

 declare
      FUNCTION test_fun (
        p_ref_cur               OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
      RETURN NUMBER is
      begin
        open p_ref_cur for select * from dual;
        return 1;
      end;

 begin
     dbms_output.put_line(test_fun(:cur));
 end;
 /
```

Answer (score 0):

This procedure did the magic

```
  PROCEDURE executecmd(cmd_in IN VARCHAR2)
          AS
          v_cv1 SYS_REFCURSOR;
          BEGIN
                 dbms_output.put_line('Executing cmd: '|| cmd);

                 execute immediate 'declare
                    result number;
                   BEGIN
                    result:='||cmd_in||';'||
                   'END;'
                   USING v_cv1;
          END;
```