# plsql function that returns num values

Tags: oracle, reporting-services, plsql

I am creating an SSRS report querying from PL/SQL and one of my parameters needs to simply call one of four integer values 30, 45, 60, or 90. I am a noob and can't get it to work what I have so far is

```
FUNCTION GET_DAYS_OUT_CL2500 RETURN NUMBER AS
  v_Days_Overdue number;
  BEGIN
       SELECT 30 AS NUM into v_Days_Overdue FROM DUAL
       UNION
       SELECT 45 AS NUM
       UNION
       SELECT 60 AS NUM
       UNION
       SELECT 90 AS NUM;
       END;
```

It is saying that my second union isn't necessary and I can not figure out the syntax of this.

Edit: Sorry for not being clear. This report is one of many reports in a Visual Studio project that are calling different functions in a plsql package. The original report would run all reports past 30 days overdue so it was written >= 30, very simple. The report now needs a drop down with an option of 30, 45, 60, 0r 90 days. 
I have taken care of the dynamic query going to the table in SSRS, this is a seperate function I am making to simple be able to send those four values to a parameter in my report so I can send them to the query that runs the data in my table. I hope this clarifies a little bit. Also these values are not dependent on any other parameter, I simply need those four values to be my parameter values.

Comment: Why do you need "into v_days_overdue"? why not select 30 as num union select 45 union select 60 union select 90

Comment: `v_Days_Overdue`  variable can take only one value at time. It is not clear what you are trying to do here. Please explain the requirement, especially what do you mean by "call one of four integer values"?

Comment: The variable `v_Days_Overdue` is defined as `number` datatype which can accept only one value. If your requirement is to return multiple values then you should use `SYS_REFCURSOR`

Comment: An example which shows the usage of [SYS_REFCURSOR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13579672/how-to-call-oracle-function-which-has-sys-refcursor-as-out-parameter)

Comment: In situations like this it is easier for everybody if you focus your question on what you know well, which is the business logic you're trying to implement. It's hard for us to reverse engineer that from some code which won't even compile. Obviously you still need to post the code, because somebody will always ask *what have you tried so far?*, but the important is you explain the end goal.

Comment: I tried that initially Harry and it gave me an error saying i needed an into statement at which point I added the variable.

Comment: @Harry I tried that and it gave me an error and said I needed an into statemet, I edited the post to explain my intentions more

Comment: @KaushikNayak I added an edit to try and explain more

Comment: @APC I added an edit to explain more

Comment: OK.. alternative approach.. if all you are trying to do is pass a parameter to the query.. and if your parameter is called days (for example) why not in SSRS.. have a days parameter with list of values of 30, 45, 60 , 90 or what ever you want. On running the report, the user can then select one of these values and you pass this to the main query.. no need for any functions or anything.. your dataset query will simply need where yourtable.yourcolumn >=@days -- assuming that is what you want to do..

Comment: So your requirement is just a dropdown List Of Values? Why do you think you need a function for that? Surely a simple query is all you need? Anyway, I definitely wasted my time writing that answer.

Comment: @CCastor1234 : sorry. I don't know much abt SSRS or visual studio, so I won't be able to tell you what suits your need the best. But, as far as I can tell, you probably won't need this function.

Comment: @Harry that only works that way if I am querying form a microsoft server unless theres some way to do that in Oracle from SSRS. I tried that and it says they are incompatible data types.

Comment: @APC I think it needs to be a function to follow the way the data is in the DB. It's a series of reports that all call from a list of functions within a procedure, I think it was done this way for ease of setting up the reports within SSRS, they all call the same datasource. I guess I couldn't think of another way to keep this little dataset within all the other data without making it a function. I am brand new at this, I'm not even out of college yet so I am quite new.